# Column containing trait names and other containing trait values - how to turn this into a workable dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a dataset containing Sample's ID, Traits, & trait values:

```
df <- data.frame( ID = c(001, 001, 001, 001, 002, 002, 002,002), Traits = c('Height','Weight','N_content','C_content','Height','Weight','N_content','C_content'),Trait_val = c(0.5,1,0.2,0.2,0.6,2,0.2,0.4)) 
print(df)
ID   Traits     Trait_val
001  Height      0.5   
001  Weight      1
001  N_content   0.2
001  C_content   0.2
002  Height      0.6
002  Weight      2
002  N_content   0.2
002  C_content   0.4
```

I would like to have a dataframe like this:

```
ID  Height  Weight N_content C_content
001 0.5     1      0.2       0.2
002 0.6     2      0.2       0.4
```

I've been thinking about filtering each trait with their corresponding IDs and trait values and then joining the dataframes to have all the data together, but I think there should be a better way to do this. Please let me know if there is a faster way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Try fro example `df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "Traits", values_from = "Trait_val")` using the `tidyr` package.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked great!